# Custom Binding in ASP.NET MVC with naming-conventions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions, model-binding, custom-binding

I've got a View where I use a naming-convention on my text-fields, to indicate what should be done with the content once it is posted back to my controller.

The format is similar to:

`<input type="text" name="RegistrationLine#ID" />`
for updates

`<input type="text" name="CreateRegistrationLine#LineNumber" />` for create

Now since I'm using this Naming-convention, regular model-binding isn't possible. But I've been reading up a bit on the subject and did find a bit of an indication that it would be possible to write a custom model binder, that should be able to help parse and bind these form elements and instantiate the objects correctly.

Please read: [Bind formValue to property of different name, ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614452/bind-formvalue-to-property-of-different-name-asp-net-mvc)

This is a bit similar to what I am doing except, I have the additional complexity of having appended information in the formelement-name that I am trying to bind to.

Am I way off base here? and if not, can any of you drop a few lines of code to show how you would start this model-binder off..

If this is a very bad approach to what I am really trying to achieve, I would love to hear suggestions for better approaches. Just note that what I want to be able to do is post back both updates and creates in one go.

Comment: I have to ask "why?".  If you replaced # with . you could take advantage of the default model binder and save yourself a lot of work.

Comment: Maybe the View Model Pattern will be the way to go in this case, as implementing a custom ModelBinder is not that simple, specially if you want it to do more that just bind.

Comment: @jfar: That's interesting. So that means I am missing some understanding of the default binder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda have to agree with @jfar and @omar.  I don't think a custom model binder is where you want to be in this instance.

You can pass a complex type to your view and simply use the full stop like @jfar mentioned.

`id="Model.Person.Name.FirstName"` will happily bind to an object named Person that has a class in it called Name that has a property called FirstName.

Now if you want to do some special checks on the data you could implement a partial class which would do the validations etc and populate the ModelState errors.

```
public partial class Name
{
  public void Validate(){ }
  public int CreateRegistrationLine(){ }
  public bool DoSpecialActions(){ }
}
```

It's a little unclear what your special actions are doing so my example above may not be what you want.