# Model Binding HTML control to Model Property with a different name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have an HTML input control on one of my views that is called for example 'BodyInput'. When I post the form I am checking if the ModelState is valid or not. The other few input controls on my view validate fine, as the name of the properties in my model are exactly the same as the name of the HTML controls, but the name of my property for the 'BodyInput' control to map to, is 'Body'.

Lets say I can't change the name of either the property in my model, or the Html input control - can I use data annotations (or anything) to map/associate the property and control for model binding?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614452/bind-formvalue-to-property-of-different-name-asp-net-mvc

Comment: No I hadn't seen that, but that looks like the sort of thing I'm after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in another question as pointed out by user ipr101.

[Bind formValue to property of different name, ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614452/bind-formvalue-to-property-of-different-name-asp-net-mvc)