# How to bind a different view html element to a model property?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a description in my model...

```
[Required]
[StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage="Description cant be more than 1000.")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
private string description;
public string Description
{
    get { return description; }
    set { description = value; }
}
```

And on my view I have...

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Description, new { cols = "60", rows = "12", @class = "focusChanger" })
```

But actually I need the textarea to be called 'myDivId' but If I change the Id in the html attributes it wont bind to the model. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

> If I change the Id in the html attributes it wont bind to the model

The `id` attribute has nothing to do with binding. It's value is never sent to the server. Feel free to change it. It's the `name` attribute of the generated `<textbox>` that is used to send the value to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: Didn't see he was talking about ID and not Name!

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this.  The first is to create a custom model binder.  See [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584) for more details.

Instead of that though, I suggest an easier way which is to create a viewmodel.  The top voted answer in [Bind formValue to property of different name, ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614452/bind-formvalue-to-property-of-different-name-asp-net-mvc) will give you an idea on how to do that.