# Object inside Model not bound when posted back

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view containing this:

```
@model RegisterInputModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register","Account", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "signup-partial-update",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}, new { id = "js-form-signup" }))
{  
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Location,"_RenderLocationInputs")
 // some more fields
}
```

And then my _RenderLocationInputs template (in VIews/Shared/EditorTemplates/)

```
@model Location
<span class="location-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="find-location" placeholder="Your Location (city)" value="@Model.ToShortString()" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.City, new { id = "hidden-location-city" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.State, new { id = "hidden-location-state" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Country, new { id = "hidden-location-country" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id, new { id = "hidden-location-id" })
</span>
```

which generates:

```
<span class="location-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="find-location" placeholder="Your Location (city)" value="" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="hidden-location-city" name="Location.City" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="hidden-location-state" name="Location.State" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="hidden-location-country" name="Location.Country" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="hidden-location-id" name="Location.Id" type="hidden" value="">
</span>
```

My controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterInputModel input)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid) return PartialView("Widgets/Register/_RegisterInput", input);
}
```

My RegisterInputModel:

```
public class RegisterInputModel : InputModel
{
   public Location Location { get; set; }
   // other fields and ctor
}
```

When inspecting the chrome POST, I see the values are correctly sent. One example: 
Loccation.City: Blabla

Though they're not bound on my mode. Is this not how the EditorFor template should be used?

I'm not sure what code you need. Just ask if you need more

Comment: Can you show your controlelr action?

Comment: can you show what html render `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.City, new { id = "hidden-location-city" })` in the end?

Comment: What does your controller action look like and what does your form look like?

Comment: I've added the code for all of you :)

Comment: As i see everything correct, what do you mean they not bound?

Comment: If I debug on my ActionResult in the controller, the RegisterInputModel.Location exists, but all valeus inside it are NULL (even if I see that my HTTPPost sent the values to the server)

Comment: Oh my God, never mind, I found it I think :)

Comment: Question: Can I bind to RegisterInputModel.Location when the partial view Model is not Location but another Model containing a location (and some other stuff)?

Comment: Note its preferable to use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Location)` and name the template `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Location.cshtml` (you will have problems if you ever need to use this template in a loop). And whats the point of overriding all the `id` attributes? And whats the point of the first (manually created) input (which wont post back!)?

Comment: And no doubt the reason its not binding is because the properties of `Location` do not have public getters and setters as I pointed out in one of your previous questions :)

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** Can I bind to RegisterInputModel.Location when the partial view Model is not Location but another Model containing a location (and some other stuff)?

Binding basically depends on `name` property of `input`, couse it posts to server. So you can change it on client side to bind different way.

The other thing is to get values manualy on controller from `HttpContext` object.

Also, you can write your own `ModelBinder` as mension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1614604/1849444), but i don't think it will help you a lot in your situation.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass to your partial the full RegisterInputModel and change this code

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.City, new { id = "hidden-location-city" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.State, new { id = "hidden-location-state" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Country, new { id = "hidden-location-country" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id, new { id = "hidden-location-id" })
```

with

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Location.City, new { id = "hidden-location-city" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Location.State, new { id = "hidden-location-state" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Location.Country, new { id = "hidden-location-country" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Location.Id, new { id = "hidden-location-id" })
```

and it should work.

Comment: The model is `Location` which contains properties `City`, `State` etc. If does **not** contain a property named `Location`. And its and `EditorTemplate`, not a Partial!